# Convert string, format 10:30AM, to which type for comparison in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have strings of the format "10:30AM", "3:00PM" etc that I want to be able to use basic operations on, for example > or < and how many hours until say 10:30 based on current time. I would like to make the conversion on the client side (javascript/jQuery) prior to database insertion.

Should I convert these to javascript date-time objects? or would a regex to change it to say a number in 24hour time format be more suitable to perform these operations on? Or am I making this more difficult than it should be?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think converting to 24h and then comparing is the best solution.

Comment: It depends on the javascript implementation of course but one would expect doing date manipulation on date objects (which are designed for it) would be fastest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are going to want to convert to a date time -- there are a lot of edge cases when comparing numbers as strings -- much easier to just bite the bullet and make a date out of it.  There are a million example libraries to use or take inspiration from.

Comment: Thanks Hogan. I thought this may be the case, the javascript Date object requires an actual date plus the time which was why I was unsure if it was a still a suitable method, but I will explore some date-time libraries

Comment: @NinjaPants - just set everything to 12 midnight -- this is standard practice for dates and use the "0" date for times.

Answer (score 1):

I personally think if it is basic operations i would convert it to 24h and then compare. If it was anything more complex then I would convert it to a date-time object.

Comment: are you saying compare as a string? what happens with 1 am vs 10 am?

Comment: Yes, 1am in 24hour format would be 01:00 which is less than 10:00. Personally I would always convert to date-time object.

Comment: It would only be so if you prefixed with the `0`

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use a library for that. I prefer [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) which allows you to perform compare or know how many hours from the current time.

Comment: I am aware of moment but have never used it, I will check it out now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit late but when you're sure you have such a specific string that needs converting in a specific way you could write your own implementation to convert the time, it'll be lighter and quicker to sort or compare:

```
var Time=function(time){
    // TODO: you an check here what format the time variable
    // is and if it's possible to convert it to time or milTime
    this.time=time;
    this.milTime=this.toMilTime();
    this.val=this.setVal();
};
Time.prototype.toMilTime=function(){
  return this.time.replace(/([0-9]{1,2}).([0-9]{1,2})([\w]{2})/,function(){
    //TODO: put this in a try catch and check if hours and numbers
    // are correct numbers. throw a new Error with the correct description
    var hours=(arguments[1].length===1)?"0"+arguments[1]:
      arguments[1],
    minutes=(arguments[2].length===1)?"0"+arguments[2]:
      arguments[2],
    pam=arguments[3].toUpperCase();
    if(pam==="PM"){
      hours=parseInt(hours,10)+12;
    }
    return hours + ":" + minutes;
  });  
};
Time.prototype.setVal=function(){
  return parseInt(this.milTime.replace(/:/,""),10);
}
// used for sorting
Time.prototype.valueOf=function(){
 return this.val;
};
// needed for <> comparison
Time.prototype.toString=function(){
 return this.milTime;
};
var t = new Time("10:30AM"),
t1=new Time("1:00PM"),
t2=new Time("10:30AM");
console.log(t.milTime,t1.milTime);
console.log(t>t1);// this will use toString()
console.log(t1>t);// this will use toString()
console.log(t===t2);//false
console.log(t==t2);//false
console.log(t.milTime===t2.milTime);//true
var arr=[t,t1,t2].sort(function(a,b){
  return a.valueOf()-b.valueOf();// force it to use valueOf
});
console.log(arr);
```